# Safe Harbor not saving settings

Tags: backup

I get this message in the CP trying to set Safe Harbor settings: Failed to save settings on http://eeharbor.com. Make sure your website is publicly accessible.

The site is publicly accessible and passes the Safe Harbor compatibility check.

Comment: I was having the same issues just the other day. It's a dev site on an IP address. I wonder if this is being thrown b/c it's not a domain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can happen for several different reasons (allowed URI characters, CURL support not being present, PHP safe_mode, errors being thrown in the ExpressionEngine install, etc..).  I would recommend opening a support request with http://EEHarbor.com

Comment: an update to the latest version of Safe Harbor solved my issue.